# No Response when using passport-local with Sailsjs

Tags: node.js, sails.js, passport.js

I'm trying to implement passport-local with sailsjs, and I am not getting any response when trying to authenticate. Here is the code:

```
//config/passport.js

var  passport = require('passport')
    , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

module.exports = {
    express: {
        customMiddleware: function(app){
            console.log('Express midleware for passport');
            app.use(passport.initialize());
            app.use(passport.session());
        }
    }
};

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, {omar: "omar"});
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {

        done(null, {omar: "omar"});

});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        // asynchronous verification, for effect...
        process.nextTick(function () {

                return done(null, {user: "omar"});

        });
    }
));
```

_

```
//LoginController.js
var passport = require('passport');
var loginController = {


    login: function(req, res){
        //res.json(req.param('username'));
        console.log('loginctrl');

        passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login', failureFlash: true }),
            function(req, res) {
                console.log('passport auth');
                res.send("success");
            }


    },

  /**
   * Overrides for the settings in `config/controllers.js`
   * (specific to LoginController)
   */
  _config: {}


};


module.exports = loginController;
```

I'm trying to POST to /login, but the only console messages I get are:

> Express midleware for passport
>   loginctrl

Meaning It's not calling LocalStrategy callback and I get "0 NO RESPONSE" error..
Why is that?

Comment: There is a typo in your `login` method on `LoginController`:         `passport.authenticate('local', ...), function(){}`  should be `passport.authenticate('local', ..., function(){})`. Also I'd move the the `passport` call to a [policy](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/policies)

Comment: Your comment was also helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something wrong with the way you call `passport.authenticate` here:

```
passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login', failureFlash: true }),
            function(req, res) {
                console.log('passport auth');
                res.send("success");
            }
```

`passport.authenticate` returns a function that is supposed to be called on request / response.

See here for some examples of Sails/Passport integration:

- https://github.com/webjames/sails-passport-example
- https://github.com/RelativeMedia/sails-PassportLocalMongoExample